# How to configure 2 LAN as input and one output ports in juniper switch

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

i would like to know how i can configure juniper "SRX100" switch such that there i can connect two LAN's for inbound traffic and one outbound traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic process is as follows:

1. Configure your VLANs

   ```
   set vlans v100-INTERNAL1 vlan-id 100
   set vlans v101-INTERNAL2 vlan-id 101
   set vlans v102-EXTERNAL vlan-id 102
   ```
2. Attach VLANs to switch ports

   ```
   set interfaces fe-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan-members v100-INTERNAL1
   set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan-members v101-INTERNAL2
   set interfaces fe-0/0/2 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan-members v102-EXTERNAL
   ```
3. Configure IP Interfaces

   ```
   set interfaces vlan unit 100 family inet address 192.168.100.1/24
   set interfaces vlan unit 101 family inet address 192.168.101.1/24
   set interfaces vlan unit 102 family inet address 192.168.102.1/24
   ```
4. Attach IP interfaces to VLANs

   ```
   set vlans v100-INTERNAL1 l3-interface vlan.100
   set vlans v101-INTERNAL2 l3-interface vlan.101
   set vlans v102-EXTERNAL l3-interface vlan.102
   ```
5. Configure a default route

   ```
   set routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.102.254
   ```
6. Create Security Zones

   ```
   set security zones security-zone INTERNAL host-inbound-traffic system-services all
   set security zones security-zone EXTERNAL host-inbound-traffic ping
   ```
7. Attach IP Interfaces to Security Zones

   ```
   set security zones security-zone EXTERNAL interfaces vlan.102
   set security zones security-zone INTERNAL interfaces vlan.100
   set security zones security-zone INTERNAL interfaces vlan.101
   ```
8. Create security policies

   ```
   set security policies from-zone INTERNAL to-zone EXTERNAL policy PERMIT-OUTBOUND match source-address any destination-address any application any
   set security policies from-zone INTERNAL to-zone EXTERNAL policy PERMIT-OUTBOUND then permit
   set security policies from-zone INTERNAL to-zone INTERNAL policy PERMIT-INTERNAL match source-address any destination-address any application any
   set security policies from-zone INTERNAL to-zone INTERNAL policy PERMIT-INTERNAL then permit
   ```

Hopefully the topology is fairly self-explanatory - just substitute the IP Addresses you wish to use.

If you are connecting to the Internet on the EXTERNAL network, I would recommend tightening up the security policies to only allow specific subnets out, and specific applications

Comment: does this code works for two inbound coupled together for one output as WAN ??

Comment: Yes, with the addition of a security policy from EXTERNAL to INTERNAL, you could easily use this configuration for a WAN connected site.